# Ajax подгрузка статей в laravel 5.5

Tags: ajax, laravel

Коллеги. Нужно сделать ajax загрузку статей. Чтобы при клике на кнопку "Смотреть еще" загружалась еще 10 статей из бд. И это все на laravel

Comment: Ошибка 419 (unknown status)

Answer (score 2):

делаете роутер для приема ajax запроса в web.php

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticlesController@get');
```

или используете существующий, далее в контроллере

```
public function get(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $data = ... выборка данных

        return responce($data, 200);
    }

}
```